# Sharing Antlr visitor code between visitors

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I have two grammar files/visitors, Simple and Complex, that parse JSON objects into strings. The Complex objects that I'm parsing can essentially contain a number of Simple objects (along with additional things). For simplicity's sake let's say that when I parse a base Simple object (not a Simple object contained within the Complex object) I want to start the string with something like "Simple start: ", but when I reach a Simple object within a Complex object I want to start it with something else, say "Simple within Complex: ".

So currently I have two different visitor classes, the Simple visitor's `visitSimpleObject` method will return the String starting with "Simple Start: " whereas the Complex visitor's `visitSimpleObject` method will return the String starting with "Simple within Complex: ". Besides this difference everything else should be the same, everything else within a Simple object can be parsed the same whether it is on it's own or inside a Complex object.

My question is, how can I share code between these two visitors? Obviously I could copy and paste all the applicable `SimpleVisitor` code into the `ComplexVisitor` but then I'll have to keep them in sync for any changes.

Note: The two visitor classes already extend a `BaseVisitor` class so I can't use typical inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance to do this, see for example:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

A short example would be something like:

```
abstract class Visitor{

    public void sharedMethod() {
        //Do something
    }

    public abstract void visitSimpleObject();
}

class SimpleVisitor extends Visitor{

    @Override
    public void visitSimpleObject() {
        System.out.println("Simple Start:");
    }
}

class ComplexVisitor extends Visitor{

    @Override
    public void visitSimpleObject() {
        System.out.println("Simple within Complex:");   
    }
}
```

In this case both your visitors would extend from the same superclass (Visitor) where the shared code is. Both subclasses can define their own behavior. The superclass can itself also extend another kind of visitor (or implement an interface).

### EDIT

After the comments maybe more like this:

Sample Ex.g4:
    grammar Ex;

```
START_COMPLEX : 'complex';
START_SIMPLE : 'simple';
SEPERATOR : ':';
TEXT : [A-Za-z]+;

simple : START_SIMPLE ' ' SEPERATOR ' ' TEXT;
complex : START_COMPLEX ' ' SEPERATOR ' ' TEXT;
```

And a code sample:

```
public class Example{

    abstract class Visitor extends ExBaseVisitor<String>{
        @Override
        public String visitComplex(ExParser.ComplexContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("Visiting complex");
            return "";
        }

    }

    class SimpleVisitor extends Visitor{
        @Override
        public String visitSimple(ExParser.SimpleContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("Visiting Simple! " + ctx.TEXT());   
            return "";
            }
    }

    class ComplexVisitor extends Visitor{

        @Override
        public String visitSimple(ExParser.SimpleContext ctx) {
            System.out.println("Visiting Simple, from within complex! " + ctx.TEXT());  
            return "";
            }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "simple : hi";
        CharStream charStream = new ANTLRInputStream(text);
        ExLexer exLexer = new ExLexer(charStream);
        TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(exLexer);
        ExParser exParser = new ExParser(tokenStream);

        ComplexVisitor complexVisitor = new Example().new ComplexVisitor();
        complexVisitor.visit(exParser.simple());

        String text2 = "simple : hmmmmm";
        CharStream charStream2 = new ANTLRInputStream(text2);
        ExLexer exLexer2 = new ExLexer(charStream2);
        TokenStream tokenStream2 = new CommonTokenStream(exLexer2);
        ExParser exParser2 = new ExParser(tokenStream2);

        SimpleVisitor simpleVisitor = new Example().new SimpleVisitor();
        simpleVisitor.visit(exParser2.simple());


    }


}
```

For me this prints:

> Visiting Simple, from within complex! hi
>
> Visiting Simple! hmmmmm

The shared code is now visitComplex which is maybe a bit silly but for the example maybe ok.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this in the original question, but the issue is my two Visitor classes already have to extend a BaseVisitor class so I can't have them extend another class

Comment: You can have the abstract class extend the BaseVisitor class?

Comment: @Harmful_Alchemist As far as I know, you can't make the ANTLR-generated classes extend a certain base class, can you?

Comment: @sepp2k I'll edit with a different example. But I may have completely misunderstood.